# Receiving error 502 BAD CONNECTION nginx when deploying django app on Google app engine

Tags: django, nginx, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, error-handling

Ive been trying to my django website but I've been having the same `502 BAD CONNECTION nginx` error every time and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it.

When I run the program using py.manager runserver, it works perfectly fine, but but I only receive an error once I run `gcloud app deploy`, looking at the logs I haven't received any errors, just one warning stating that `Container called exit(1).`

I've tried one solution from the Google's website: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors and I added `resources: memory_gb: 4` to my app.yaml file and I still end up with an error.

I am not sure this is of much help my app.yaml currently looks like this:

```
runtime: python39

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto

resources:
  memory_gb: 4
```

And my gcloudignore looks like this:

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore
secret_variables.py
.venv
Pipfile
Pipfile.lock

# Python pycache:
__pycache__/
# Ignored by the build system
/setup.cfg
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Do you have the code you are trying to deploy somewhere in github?

Comment: @jabbson, yup heres the link: https://github.com/yousefsaid/test

Comment: I added some of the requirements from the pip file and I just realized some of the installations are overlapping

Comment: you are missing django-filter in the requirements

Comment: I didnt even realize that, thank you for your help @jabbson!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloned and tried running the code locally after running pip install -r requirements.txt. This is the error I got:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'`

This means that this requirement needs to be added before the code is deployed to the GAE.

add `django-filter` to the requirements.txt file to fix it.